# Removing items from vector string C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector, it's contents are like so..

```
std::vector<string> vec;

vec.push_back("XXXX_LLLL");
vec.push_back("XXXX_HHHH");
vec.push_back("XXXX_XXXX");
```

I'd like to iterate over the vector and remove the "_" from the string. I've tried using the find-erase idiom as so, with a struct I made to find _.

```
vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), IsUnderScore2()),vec.end());
```

But I realized it's not iterating over each individual string in my vector string, so it will never erase the underscore. Is there another method of iterating over a vector, and it's individual components, that can help me here?

Comment: You're going to have to *go deeper* here and iterate over the characters of the things you're iterating over, or use a transform as Chad suggests.

Comment: Did you think of searching for an answer before posting your question?   See the "Related" list over there -->

Comment: @liquid See my updated post. It contains all you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate through the `vector` and use the erase-remove idiom on each string, instead of on the `vector` elements as you're doing right now

```
std::vector<string> vec;

vec.push_back("XXXX_LLLL");
vec.push_back("XXXX_HHHH");
vec.push_back("XXXX_XXXX");

for(auto& str : vec) {
  str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '_'), 
            str.end());
}
```

---

C++03 version:

```
for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = vec.begin(), it != vec.end(), ++it) {
  it->erase(std::remove(it->begin(), it->end(), '_'), 
            it->end());
}
```

Comment: Your `remove_if` is just a `remove` with extra stuff. (I do that sometimes.)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with using a for loop with 'auto' I'll have to look up this implementation, I've tried using it and my compiler is complaining.. I don't think my version of C++ supports this implementation. Here is my error: warning: ‘auto’ will change meaning in C++0x; please remove it

Comment: @liquid I've added the C++03 version. You might be able to get the first version to compile if you add the `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` if you have an older compiler) switch to the compiler command line.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I will try to play around with adding the C++ 11 options to my compiler. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following. You can use standard algorithm `std::remove` applied to each string of the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    vec.push_back("XXXX_LLLL");
    vec.push_back("XXXX_HHHH");
    vec.push_back("XXXX_XXXX");

    for ( std::string &s : vec )
    {
        s.erase( std::remove( s.begin(), s.end(), '_'), s.end() );
    }

    for ( const std::string &s : vec ) std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
XXXXLLLL
XXXXHHHH
XXXXXXXX
```

If your compiler does not support the C++ 2011 then you can write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    vec.push_back("XXXX_LLLL");
    vec.push_back("XXXX_HHHH");
    vec.push_back("XXXX_XXXX");

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it )
    {
        it->erase( std::remove( it->begin(), it->end(), '_'), it->end() );
    }

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it )
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This also worked! Wish I could claim multiple answers, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Using **regular expressions** would look like :

```
for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](string &str) {
    regex_replace(str.begin(), str.begin(), str.end(), regex("_"), "");
});
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aea846212c1fc115)

A range based for loop version might be more readable :

```
for(auto &str : vec) {
    regex_replace(str.begin(), str.begin(), str.end(), regex("_"), "");
}
```